# Android create a PreferenceFragment without a PreferenceActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I added a side menu to my Application and I managed to change the content with fragments. Now I am trying to do the Preferences, but I **don't** want to use a `PreferenceActivity` because I want to do my application with fragments because I don't want to do the NavigationDrawer twice (For my main activity displaying the fragments and for the PreferenceActivity).
I found the class `PreferenceFragment` but after alot of research I found out that appearantly it just is a part of the SettingsActivity and when I try to `addPreferenceFromResouce` in the PreferenceFragment and then launch the fragment, it crashes.

So basically I am trying to find a way to display a SettingsFragment without any extra activity just by calling `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentFrame, settingsFragment).commit()` just as I do with my different fragments.

I hope I asked my question understandable (I am sorry if I didn't). Thanks for your time and your help.

Comment: Did you get any answer?

Comment: I found an answer myself. I will include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself now. It wasn't very hard.
I simply created a normal `PreferenceFragment` and you can use it like any other fragment without a PreferenceActivity.

```
public class PreferenceFragment extends android.preference.PreferenceFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}}
```

I then replaced it using

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentFrame, preferenceFragment).commit();
```

as you normally would.

This worked great for me. I hope it also does for you.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have a tabbed activity and it conflicts with the tabs.